# How do I put social icons next to each other?

Tags: html, icons

Does anyone know how I can put social icons next to each other?

At the moment they are underneath each other but I need to find a way to have them next to each other.

Please have a look at what I mean here: [Website](https://www.hypematrix.co.uk/)

Thanks

Comment: First of all, each of your image is in a `<p>`, which already should give a clue that it will be a separate paragraph. Secondly your images have inline style, specifically `display: block` - that's your second clue it will be on separate line. This is a good example why inline styles is highly NOT RECOMMENDED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have each icon enclosed in `<p>` which means it will be on a separate line.
Than you have `display: block;` set for each icon, this will also force it on separate line. Remove both these and they will be displayed in one line, enclose all icons into one container so you can position them in the center.

```css
/* fixed */
.footer.media img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}


/* fixed + alternative */
div.footer {
  text-align: center;
}

/* alternative */

.footer.media2 > a[title]:before
{
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.footer.media2 > a[title="Facebook"]:before
{
  background-image: url('https://www.hypematrix.co.uk/Facebook.png');
}
.footer.media2 > a[title="Twitter"]:before
{
  background-image: url('https://www.hypematrix.co.uk/Twitter.png');
}
.footer.media2 > a[title="YouTube"]:before
{
  background-image: url('https://www.hypematrix.co.uk/YouTube.png');
}
.footer.media2 > a[title="Linkedin"]:before
{
  background-image: url('https://www.hypematrix.co.uk/Linkedin.png');
}


/* ignore this */

body {
  background-color: #3A456C;
  color: white;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h3>Original:</h3>
<p>
  <a title="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/hypematrixuk" target="_blank">
    <img style=" display: block;  margin-left: auto;  margin-right: auto; " src="https://www.hypematrix.co.uk/Facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="30" height="30">
  </a>
</p>
<p>
  <a title="Twitter" href="https://twitter.com/hype_matrix" target="_blank">
    <img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://www.hypematrix.co.uk/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter" width="30" height="30">
  </a>
</p>
<p>
  <a title="YouTube" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXh7RLCAsx8p8U4eDc_CJg" target="_blank">
    <img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://www.hypematrix.co.uk/YouTube.png" alt="YouTube" width="30" height="30">
  </a>
</p>
<p>
  <a title="Linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/hype-matrix/" target="_blank">
    <img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://www.hypematrix.co.uk/Linkedin.png" alt="Linkedin" width="30" height="30">
  </a>
</p>


<h3>Fixed:</h3>
<div class="footer media">
  <a title="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/hypematrixuk" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.hypematrix.co.uk/Facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
  <a title="Twitter" href="https://twitter.com/hype_matrix" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.hypematrix.co.uk/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></a>
  <a title="YouTube" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXh7RLCAsx8p8U4eDc_CJg" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.hypematrix.co.uk/YouTube.png" alt="YouTube"></a>
  <a title="Linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/hype-matrix/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.hypematrix.co.uk/Linkedin.png" alt="Linkedin"></a>
</div>



<h3>Alternative no &lt;img&gt;:</h3>
<div class="footer media2">
  <a title="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/hypematrixuk" target="_blank"></a>
  <a title="Twitter" href="https://twitter.com/hype_matrix" target="_blank"></a>
  <a title="YouTube" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXh7RLCAsx8p8U4eDc_CJg" target="_blank"></a>
  <a title="Linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/hype-matrix/" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have done that but I'm struggling to find a way to center them now?

Comment: I've figured it out. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You don't believe in CSS, do you? It seems everything is done via HTML on your page...very bad practice... Anyhow, added "alternative" example method, which shows images from css

Answer (score 1):

--- There are more ways to do that / only an example with flex ---

You can use Flexbox for that. Heres a small example:

(I'm using font awesome for the icons)

```css
.myDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.myDiv p {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#3A456C;">

<div class="myDiv">
<p><a title="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/hypematrixuk" target="_blank"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://www.hypematrix.co.uk/Facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="30" height="30" /></a></p>
<p><a title="Twitter" href="https://twitter.com/hype_matrix" target="_blank"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://www.hypematrix.co.uk/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter" width="30" height="30" /></a></p>
<p><a title="YouTube" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXh7RLCAsx8p8U4eDc_CJg" target="_blank"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://www.hypematrix.co.uk/YouTube.png" alt="YouTube" width="30" height="30" /></a></p>
<p><a title="Linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/hype-matrix/" target="_blank"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://www.hypematrix.co.uk/Linkedin.png" alt="Linkedin" width="30" height="30" /></a></p>
</div>

</body>
```

If you want them to be under each other add "flex-direction: column" to the myDiv styling. Here's an example with the code of the given website.

Comment: I've tired to add this to the index file but it doesn't work? am I missing something?

Comment: they don't *need* flex for that

Comment: @vanowm I know but there are so many ways to do that. Im using flex for those kind of things because its very easy to use. MotorHype please provide your current HTML and css code in your question.

Comment: It won't let me post the code here, it's all in the index file, just click view page source.

Comment: @MotorHype I've updated my answer with the code of the website. As I said there are more solutions than only this one. Flex can be very useful but you need to understand how it works. Check out some tutorials it's super easy to learn. For this small example its kinda "overkill" but it works fine.